# How To Format Scale Numbers in Chart.js v2

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

First of all, I apologize if my question is a slightly the same as others question. I searched for a solution and found 3 similar questions, yet none of them worked in my case, because the examples I found use Chart.js v1.

I saw a sample using a function placed in `scaleLabel` to format the numbers just like this:

```
var options = {
    animation: false,
    scaleLabel: function(label){
        return  '$' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
};
```

The above code, however, doesn't work anymore in the new Chart.js v2.

How can I format the scale numbers in Chart.js v2?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/2n7xc7j7/

Answer (score 0):

When adding option configurations, you need to make sure you nest the settings in the right sections. You can format the scale numbers by adding a `callback` function to the `yAxes` [ticks configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) section:

```
options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: function(value) {
                    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2n7xc7j7/1/

Answer (score 0):

In V3 the [`locale`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/locale.html) property has been added. This makes it so all the numbers on the scales an tooltips get formatted correctly automatically in the numberformat of that country code:

```js
// Element
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")

// Data
const data = {
  labels: ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Sample',
    data: [2982, 1039, 3200, 2300],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(90, 150, 220, 0.85)",
    borderColor: "rgba(70, 120, 180, 1)",
    borderWidth: 2
  }],
}

// Options
const options = {
  locale: 'en-US'
};

const chart_trans_hari = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this:

http://profwtelles.ddns.net/grafico2.html

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
    new Chart(canvas, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'A',
                yAxisID: 'A',
                data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
            }, {
                label: 'B',
                yAxisID: 'B',
                data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: 'A',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                }, {
                    id: 'B',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right',
                    ticks: {
                        max: 1,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope to help you.
Best Regards