# Chartjs v2.5 - only show min and max on scale, absolute positioning on scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I created a very simple line chart, for use on mobile devices. I find that when I include the scale, it takes up a lot of space on the side of the chart.

Instead, what I've seen accomplished on other mobile charts is only showing the minimum and the maximum value. A user can use the tooltip to find specifics.

Anyway, I'm hoping someone can show me how to create a scale such as the one here:

[image: wanted output]

The two main takeaways of this scale:

1. Only the min and max values are shown
2. They are shown with absolute positioning approximately in the top left and bottom right corners.

---

My thought process was possibly using the `scaleOverride`, then just defining `scaleSteps : 1` with a `scaleStepWidth` equal to the difference between the min and max of my data. Even if this is on the right track, I don't know how I would override the positioning of the scale to be absolute and not take space away from the line itself.

Comment: Can you add your code or a JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ujsg9w8r/  ... Here's a fiddle of my chart as it exists now. I messed around with the scale but didn't have much luck so I left it as I have it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've broken this answer down into the steps needed to get your chart to look like the provided image:

#### 1. Only show max and min labels

First, use JavaScript [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) methods to determine the highest and lowest values in the data array:

```
var min = Math.min(...data);
var max = Math.max(...data);
```

Then, add the following options to the `yAxes` [ticks configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) section:

- Set the `max` and `min` values to the data array max and min values.
- Set `stepSize` to the difference between the max and min value. This will ensure that it only shows the highest and lowest numbers in the labels.

#### 2. Move labels to inside the right side of the chart

This can be done in two steps:

- Add `position: "right"` to move the align the scale `yAxes` to the right side of the chart.
- Set `mirror: true` in the ticks configuration to flip the labels over the `yAxes`, to get them to show inside the chart.

#### 3. Format number with dollar sign and 2 decimal places

To format the numbers with a dollar sign and two decimal places, add a `callback` function to the ticks options:

```
callback: function(value) {
    return '$' + value.toFixed(2);
}
```

See [How To Format Scale Numbers in Chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630102/how-to-format-scale-numbers-in-chart-js-v2/44053860#44053860) and [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript) for more information.

#### 4. Change color or hide the `yAxes` grid line

Although your question is about changing the color of the grid line, based on the provided image, I am assuming you want to remove the `yAxes` line. To remove the grid line, set `drawBorder` to `false` in the [grid line configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) settings.

If you do want to change the grid line color to white, `color: "#fff"` will work, you just need to make sure that you put that line in the `gridLines` config section like:

```
gridLines: {
    color: "#fff"
}
```

#### 5. Change label font formatting

This wasn't in your questions, but if you want to change to label font color and sizing, simply use the `fontColor` and `fontSize` tick config options.

#### Final `yAxes` code:

```
yAxes: [{
    id: 'share_price',
    type: 'linear',
    position: "right",
    gridLines: {
        display: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        //color: "#fff"
    },
    ticks: {
        stepSize: max - min,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        mirror: true,
        fontColor: "#fff",
        fontSize: 18,
        callback: function(value) {
            return '$' + value.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
}]
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ujsg9w8r/5/

Comment: Thank you! JS is not my strong suit, so I appreciate this.  Two quick follow-ups: I notice in your fiddle, the number is formatted `12.3` without any excess JS. How can I go about getting it to display as `$12.30` ... Second, any idea how to change the color of the black yaxis line? Setting `color: "#ffffff"` only changes the text, not the line.

Comment: @itwasluck3 I've updated my answer to include the followup questions. I've also updated the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Fantastic. Very much appreciated! Your step-by-step is incredibly valuable from a learning perspective. Cheers!